# Send email with multiple attachments using python with Twilio send grid

Tags: azure-functions, twilio, sendgrid, email-attachments

I'm using Twilio sendgrid for emails. During my Azure function execution, I'm saving multiple files of different file types in temp directory. How can I pick all those files from temp directory and send multiple attachments in a single email using Python. Throwing error "can't set attribute" at message.attachments = list(lst_attchments)

```
message = Mail(
from_email='from_mail',
to_emails='to_mail',
subject='sample mail from fun2 part-no data - 123490-000',
html_content='<stron>mr. venkatesh, please find the updated data and let me know if any issues. \n regards,System</strong>')
#mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('sendgridkey'))
    #message.add_attachment(temp_path+'//'+'test_file2.pdf')
    files = ["test_file.pdf", "test_file2.pdf", "test_file1.pdf"]

    lst_attchments=[]
    for file_name in files:  # add files to the message
        file_path = os.path.join(temp_path, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_data:
            data = file_data.read()
            file_data.close()
        encoded_file = base64.b64encode(data).decode()

        attachedFile = Attachment(
            FileContent(encoded_file),
            FileName(file_name),
            FileType('application/pdf'),
            Disposition('attachment')
        )
        lst_attchments.append(attachedFile)
    message.attachments = list(lst_attchments)
    
    mail_json = message.get()        
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_json)
    logging.info('mail sent succefully')
    
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

Comment: check the documentation and this blog: https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-email-attachments-with-twilio-sendgrid-python

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share the code you are using? What have you tried? Were there any errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*As suggested by @Olasimbo Arigbabu and as per the [twilio document](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-email-attachments-with-twilio-sendgrid-python) here is the sample code for sending email through python using twilio and by attaching files.*

```
import os
import base64
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType, Disposition)
message = Mail(from_email='from_email@example.com',to_emails='to@example.com',
subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>'
)
with  open('attachment.pdf', 'rb') as f:
data = f.read()
f.close()
encoded_file = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachedFile = Attachment(
FileContent(encoded_file),
FileName('attachment.pdf'),
FileType('application/pdf'),
Disposition('attachment')
)
message.attachment = attachedFile
sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
response = sg.send(message)
print(response.status_code, response.body, response.headers)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question I think. This is still a single file. Not sure why this was accepted as answer.

Comment: this only works for single file, not for multiple. Doesn't answer original question

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
        lst_attchments.append(attachedFile)
    message.attachments = list(lst_attchments)
```

to

```
        lst_attchments.append(attachedFile)
    message.attachment = lst_attachments
```

Then it works. At least I have tested and it worked here.